# Codeigniter 3.0 routing problems

Tags: php, url-routing, codeigniter-3

I'm new in Codeigniter framework and got routing problem.
I have Main controller and Tournaments controller.
My routes look like this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'main';
$route['main'] = 'main';
$route['tournaments/results/(:num)'] = 'tournaments/results/$1';
```

When I go to `localhost/tournaments/results/1` and then click to link "Main" I got `localhost/tournaments/results/main` instead of `localhost/main`

What is wrong with my routes or maybe problem is somewhere else?

Comment: use base_url()  for your link.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your link to 'Main' is wrong, not your routes files. Check your link.

Comment: It is a regular link: <li><a href="main">Main</a></li>